# UIBarButtonItem no longer working after updating to IOS 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, uibarbuttonitem

I have a `UIBarButtonItem` that I created inside the interface builder. Before updating to IOS 8.1 everything was working fine, but after the update it doesn't seem like the navigation bar that holds the `UIBarButtonItem` is even catching touch events anymore.

I present the view that contains the UIBarButtonItem modally like this:

```
editNoteVC=[[EditNoteView alloc]initWithNibName:@"EditNoteView_iPad" bundle:nil];
editNoteVC.delegate=self;
editNoteVC.modalPresentationStyle =UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
[self presentViewController:editNoteVC animated:NO completion:nil];
[editNoteVC release];
```

I have an `IBAction` inside of `EditNoteView` that is supposed to respond to the users clicking on the left bar button item (which is `Cancel`):

```
-(IBAction)cancelButtonPressed:(id)sender;
{
    NSLog("Cancel button pressed.");
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];    
}
```

When I click on the cancel button, it doesn't even animate anymore and my code never prints out "Cancel button pressed" like it used to before the update.

There is no code for the two UIBarButtonItems since I created them in the interface builder, so nothing could've changed there.

I have looked all over and I cannot find anything that says that `UIBarButtonItem` has changed somehow or what I have suddenly done wrong. Any ideas?

Comment: Try breaking the action message link inside IB, then reattach it and see if that helps. Otherwise, its possible another view is eating the touches - if it overlaps the button.

Comment: @DavidH I tried breaking the link already and reattaching it. Ive also searched throughout my entire code for touch events and I am having no luck :(

Comment: These are maddening problems, I still think touch is disabled for your bar. Try adding a pure button at the top of your view, see if it works. Also, you can add a button as the titleView property on the navItem, see if it works. Its possible but unlikely that your storyboard/nib is corrupt. Try varying things and get back to a point where things worked, then add things back in. Some HUDs would put a transparent view over a view to provide a dimming affect, if that happened and the view was not removed all touches would be blocked.